Export to Excel Date and Time Fields
we're stumped on an issue when exporting a Document Library containing Date and Field times to Excel.  Two columns in SharePoint are of type Date and Time (see attachment).....when we export to Excel, the formatting changes to string (see attached image).   We can of course go into the Excel doc and change the formatting of the column, but we don't want our customer to do that.  How can we maintain the integrity of the Date and Time formatting when exporting to Excel? 
